# Capture the PointerWheelChanged event in gridview

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a gridview; if unpopulated I can use the pointerwheelchanged event but, if i implement gridview, for example, with 1000 items, so i can use the gridview scrollview, the pointerwheelchanged is no longer intercepted because now there are the items in "front".
How can I use pointerwheelchanged even after I implement gridview with, for example, 100 items?

without items work:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GridView x:Name="GridViewItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="338" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="583" PointerWheelChanged="vivvio_PointerWheelChanged" Background="#FF86C441">

        </GridView>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtScroll" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="102" Width="583"/>
    </StackPanel>

    int cont = 1;
    private void GridViewItems_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtScroll.Text = cont.ToString();
        cont += 1;
    }
```

with items not work:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <GridView x:Name="GridViewItems" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="338" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="583" PointerWheelChanged="vivvio_PointerWheelChanged" Background="#FF86C441">
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
        <GridViewItem FontSize="48" Content="Item"/>
    </GridView>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtScroll" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="102" Width="583"/>
</StackPanel>

int cont = 1;
private void GridViewItems_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtScroll.Text = cont.ToString();
    cont += 1;
}
```

thanks for help!!

Comment: Your `PointerWheelChanged` instance is `vivvio_PointerWheelChanged` but i the backend you are looking for `GridViewItems_PointerWheelChanged`.?

Comment: No... sorry...  my code is correct (there isn't such error) but the problem described there is anyway... help me...

Comment: Its not an error. Look at `PointerWheelChanged` in your xaml for `GridView` it literally says `vivvio_PointerWheelChanged`. and the c# code you have in your answer is `GridViewItems_PointerWheelChanged`?

Comment: Here is a [sample](https://github.com/avknaidu/SOIssue45063788) on github. Feel free to download and replicate the issue for yourself. Works perfectly fine on the repro.

Comment: sorry again... In the code that I posted there is the error but, in the project on my computer there isn't error ... and despite this the pointerwheelchanged doesn''t work...

Comment: Ok. Check the sample i uploaded on Github. See if you are still able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Place the correct code that i need to use (which does not work)

Answer (score 0):

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    int cont = 1;
    private void GridViewItems_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtScroll.Text = cont.ToString();
        cont += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found solution: https://fiercedesign.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/windows-8-nested-gridview-scrolling/